# How to run automated test cases through MTM 2015

Tags: automation, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, tfs-2015, mtm

I am trying to execute automated test cases (codedui) from Microsoft Test Manager 2015. I have executed by triggering tfs bui. But my requirement is to run through MTM 2015.

So far I have done the following:

1. Created an environment in lab - MTM
2. Created XAML Build definition

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run code ui test through MTM, seems not related to XAML build. 
What you need to do is importing the test methods to TFS as test case and then which can be added to MTM through [tcm testcase /import](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff942471(v=vs.120).aspx)

Such as creating test suites which are tied to the CodedUI tests, and use these sub-selections of tests to complete a test run that validates a specific change made to the system.

More detail steps please refer this tutorial: [How to manage and run CodedUI tests using Microsoft Test Manager](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/manage-codeui-tests)